# Can not tnsping but can sqlplus connect

Tags: oracle11g

I have a question hopefully someone could explain it to me. I have an Oracle 11g installed properly on the server. From a workstation, I have installed the oracle client which tnsname.ora pointed to the Oracle database. I can ping to the server where oracle db was installed. I can sqlplus connect to the database and I can even connect to the database programmatically using C#. However, I can not tnsping to it. I got error Message 3511 not found when trying to do so. So my question is: in what scenario tnsping is used and how do I make tnsping works? In other word, if my tnsping does not work but I still can connect to the database programmatically using C#, what are the concerns that I should be worrying about? I am new to Oracle.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to do the following actions without success although they are the most popular answers to similar scenario similar to mine.

```
1) Set Oracle_Sid to my oracle sid
2) Set Oracle_Home to my oracle home directory
```

What I did to solve the issue:

```
1) Uninstall oracle client
2) Reinstall the oracle client with the newest version 11.2.xx.
```

I believe, re-installing the oracle client of earlier version would just work as well. 
However, since I have to re-install the client, I might want to get the newest version. 
The cause is probably improper installation at the first time as we have an disk image of pre-installed application to automatically prep a new computer. 
Not able tnsping does not seem to impede with other Oracle operations (at least not that I know of).

If someone knows what is the limitation of not able to tnsping but can sqlplus connect, ping... , I would appreciate if you could share.

Answer (score 0):

Either your $Oracle_Home value is not set or your default sid is not set in $ORACLE_SID

Try this :

```
set ORACLE_SID=mysid
export ORACLE_SID
tnsping mysid
```

and see what it comes back with.

Comment: Thanks! I am using windows. Is export a windows command? I got the error saying export is not recognized as internal or external command in windows 7.

Comment: export is for Linux installations.
for windows installations just use the set command and it will set a variable for your current cmd session only.
If you want to make it a permanent setting you need to add it to your variables in Computer Properties

Comment: adding it in the variables from Windows does not work. I still have the same issue. The weird thing is it only happen to some workstation only. I have 1 workstation that does not have tnsping issue and the other has. Not sure where to check anymore. The places that needed to be checked or mentioned by everyone (Oracle_Home, Oracle_SID) were checked and they are identical. My oracle_home are in both ws, Oracle_SID has not be in any of my WS...